# What is the better way to know the sum of children's width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a horizontal div with a random number of children ; this div has a `overflow: hidden` property so some of the children are hidden and can be visible when we navigate through the div with a click on some specific buttons (basically previous/next buttons).

To force the navigation in the parent div, I'm using `.scrollLeft()`. So when we press *previous*, I make something like `scrollLeft(actualscrollLeft - parent.outerWidth())`, and when we press *next*, I make something like `scrollLeft(actualscrollLeft + parent.outerWidth())`. So far so good (I think so actually).

I want to know when we reach the end of the navigation (like that, I can go back to the start of the children elements when we press *next*).

I'm doing the following to perform this :

```
var list_width = jQlist.outerWidth(),
    actualScroll = jQlist.scrollLeft(),
    fullsize = 0,
    jQitems = jQuery(jQlist.find('.item'));

for(var i = 0; i < jQitems.length; i++) { fullsize = fullsize + jQuery(jQitems[i]).outerWidth(); }

if(actualScroll  + list_width >= fullsize) { jQlist.scrollLeft(0); }
else { jQlist.scrollLeft(actualScroll + list_width); }
```

It works great, but I'm wondering if it's the better way to perform this (in a "performance" way I mean).

Further details :

The total number of the children can't be known and the number of children displayed at once through the parent div depends of the screen width, everything is calculated with css before.
No matter how many children are displayed at once, it always fit the entire parent div.

As an example with 4 children, in a large screen the parent div can display 3 items and the next view displays the last item, and in a small screen the first view displays 2 items and the next one also two.

Comment: There are three possible outcomes to this question which is, are all the items; less than the width of the parent, more than the width of the parent or a mix?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I just add some details which can answer your question : no matter how many children are displayed at once, they always fit the whole parent div.
So if there is the parent div is made to show 2 items and there are 3 items, the first view of the parent div shows 2 items (width 50% for each item) and the second view of the parent div show 1 item (width 100% for the item).
Please tell me if I'm not clear.

Comment: Second question after you updated your question.  When click next to the last item which is less than the width of the parent, means that the left of the last child element will not be on the left side of the parent.  Is that something that you've taken into account.  Secondly is the scrollbar visible?

Comment: @ErikPhilips the last child even if it's alone to shown will fit to the view so will be completly visible . There is no scrollbar, I don't want to ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `Document.createRange` & `Range.getBoundingClientRect()`:

```js
let range = document.createRange();

const row = document.querySelector('.row');

range.setStart(row.firstChild, 0);
range.setEnd(row.lastChild, row.lastChild.childNodes.length);

console.log('Parent = ', row.getBoundingClientRect());
console.log('Children = ', range.getBoundingClientRect());
```

```css
.row {
  display:   flex;
  max-width: 3em;
  font-size: 2rem;
  overflow:  scroll;
  cursor:    col-resize;
}

/* Hide scrollbars in chrome */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbars in FF */
.row {
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

```html
<div class = "row">
  <div class = "cell">A</div>
  <div class = "cell">B</div>
  <div class = "cell">A</div>
  <div class = "cell">B</div>
  <div class = "cell">A</div>
  <div class = "cell">B</div>
  <div class = "cell">A</div>
  <div class = "cell">B</div>
  <div class = "cell">A</div>
  <div class = "cell">B</div>
  <div class = "cell">A</div>
  <div class = "cell">B</div>
  <div class = "cell">A</div>
  <div class = "cell">B</div>
  <div class = "cell">A</div>
  <div class = "cell">B</div>
  <div class = "cell">A</div>
  <div class = "cell">B</div>
  <div class = "cell">A</div>
  <div class = "cell">B</div>
  <div class = "cell">A</div>
  <div class = "cell">B</div>
</div>
```

```
Parent =  {
  "x": 8,
  "y": 8,
  "width": 96,
  "height": 52,
  "top": 8,
  "right": 104,
  "bottom": 60,
  "left": 8
}

Children =  {
  "x": 8,
  "y": 8,
  "width": 488.984375,
  "height": 37,
  "top": 8,
  "right": 496.984375,
  "bottom": 45,
  "left": 8
}
```

Comment: Very nice one ! With a quick benchmark test, my method takes ~54ms to be done 1000 times, yours takes ~3ms to be done 1000 times ! Impressive. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

So you have a div with a specific view range, and the item inside that overpass that will not show up until you scroll with a button event.

well, your code is fine, few things you can do are to avoid child selection and adding the with the fullsize. to do that you can wrap your items in parent div with x-overflow allowed and then you can get that div width it will be cleaner.

in css to keep the scrollbar not visible

```
.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.wrapper {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't want the scrollbar to be shown because I just want to be able to navigate with the two buttons ^^. Or maybe I didn't understand your suggestion ?

Comment: you can keep it follow with a hidden scrollbar, i update the response